# Respect, attachment to position and aversion to disrespect. (In Buddhism)

Tags: attachment

One thing that is very easy to see in Buddhism is how respect is important. Respect for books, statues of Buddha and monks.

At the same time we learn that attachment and aversion are bad things.

Can't this respect for monks and traditions (sitting in a lower place, not pointing, etc) become an attachment to rules and reputation? At the same time, can't the disrespect for such rules become aversion?

Comment: Instead of "be seen as", which is not really consequential to a Buddhist, replace with "become" and I think you already have the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Respect should first be given to the truth of suffering, to the truth of the cause of suffering, and the capacity of the dhamma to free you from that. Why? Because if you have no respect for the capacity of the fire to burn you, or the balm to sooth you, then you will only continue to burn.

Respect should be given to the Buddha, as a practitioner who accomplished something very profound and difficult, something noble and worthwhile, and then chose to share the wisdom of how he accomplished that with us all. He should be respected as someone who can teach us valuable lessons. When we see a statue or an image of the Buddha, we respect what it represents, the accomplishment and nobility of what was conquered.

Respect should be given to those serious practitioners who have set themselves out to follow the path laid out by the Buddha, to take it upon themselves to accomplish what amount of that great work that they can. It is hard work, arduous work that requires diligence, and is worthy of respect.

If we respect these good qualities, we will be likely to emanate them. If we do that, we may become free of our suffering. It is good to do so.

This is why.

Comment: Great! I do respect the triple gem, very very much, I was asking just to know how other people see it :)

Comment: Actually, the Buddha comes first, then the Dhamma and the Sangha.

Comment: @SankhaKulathantille I would argue that before it is possible to even know why respect for the Buddha is appropriate, understanding the truth of what he taught is necessary. Even then you have to respect yourself enough to apply the teaching, to learn the truth of what it is that is respectable. There are ways to approach respect, and obviously the truth of the Enlightened One is paramount, but to even understand what that means, you start with the truths themselves. Regardless, this is not the refuge vow, so there is no "traditional" or canonical order.

Comment: Without the Buddha, we wouldn't have any Dhamma to learn in the first place. Also, learning is one thing and respecting is another.

Comment: I can see what you mean, but it is also noteworthy that the truth is the truth weather or not someone points it out. But that is besides the point, like I mentioned, because this topic is not concerning the refuge vow, so there is no "proper" order as such. If you feel strongly about your view, that's great. For me, gaining deep respect for the Buddha meant, specifically, learning and therefore having the ability to understand and respect the Dhamma, to understand and respect what he accomplished, within my capacity to do so. Without that, what is there to respect? Just a name.

Comment: There is a proper order. Even before the refuge vow, we say "Namo tassa bhagavato arahato samma sambuddhassa" -  Homage to the Blessed One, the Exalted One, the fully Enlightened One! That's the 1st statement of respect.  Even though the truth is the truth even when there's no Buddha, you wouldn't know what is the truth unless the Buddha preaches it to you first.

Comment: What tradition are you? Clearly this is an important issue for you, and one that apparently touches on your tradition's prescription for what is considered proper. Like I said, for me, the value of respect came in a very straightforward way, as I experienced it, to learn to respect the Dhamma, and thereby realize the respect appropriate to the Buddha, as he is described to us via the various traditions.

Comment: Regardless, this is not about placing one above the other, not in the least. From the perspective that I am writing from, it is more about an order of realization. Anyway. Be well.

Comment: When you learn the Dhamma and understand it, your respect for the Buddha grows. But that doesn't define the order. The Maha Brahma himself paid homage to the Buddha before the Buddha even preached a single sutta. I'm just stating the order of the common practice. Whether it's important or not is s a different matter.

Comment: @SankhaKulathantille The Buddha himself revered the Dhamma as his superior...

Comment: Yes, Bhante @yuttadhammo , as I've heard, the Buddha placed the Dhamma as his teacher since he thought it's not good to be without a teacher. But are you familiar with any tradition where they pay homage to the Dhamma first and then the Buddha and the Sangha?

Comment: @SankhaKulathantille this topic is better suited for chat, but I am not aware of any teaching that puts the Buddha higher than the Dhamma. Just coming first is not evidence to that end; Sila comes before Samadhi, impermanence before suffering, etc.

Comment: I agree Bhante! I was mostly arguing about the correct order. Even with the refuge, it would be weird if someone started with "Dhammam Saranam Gachchami"

Comment: Any difference between Bhante and Banthe? I have read both... are both correct?

Answer (score 0):

Aversion and attachment is due to polarity of perception. (Ignorance is clouding due to perception, unskilled and scattered nature of our mind.)

By reducing perception or riding itself through meditation will help you avoid such dilemmas either way you choose to do.

Since the world runs on perception and all worldly people are polarized by perception, as an inspiration to others it would be wise to slant yourself to what is generally accepted as pious and good. (But not driven by attachments or perception. )